# My Javascript function setInterval() runs only 43 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have a javascript code in which I used setInterval() function to fetch data from mysql database and insert into google sheet every  1 sec of delay .. well forget my main target why I am doing this and please tell me that why this code runs only 43 times every time I execute, also when I use "For Loop" that also work for 43 times..can anybody tell what is the "SECRET OF 43".

Here is my code..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#insert").click(function(){
    var i = 1;
    var total = "<?php echo $count;?>"; 
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
   if (i < total) { 
     $.post("get.php",
        {
          id: i
        },
        function(data,status){
            //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            var arr = [];
            json = JSON.stringify(eval('(' + data + ')')); //convert to json string
            arr = $.parseJSON(json); //convert to javascript array

$.post("GOOGLE-WEB-APP-URL-HERE",
        {
          impression: arr[0],
          revenue   : arr[1],
          clicks    : arr[2]
        },
        function(returndata,status){
            //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            $("#succeed").html(returndata);
        });
        });
      i++;
   }
   else { 
      clearInterval(interval);
   }
}, 1000);

});
});
</script>
```

Please note that this code is working only 43 times whether "total" value is 50.please let me know if you want anything else..I think you don't need google app script because I don't thinks there is any problem..by the way please let me know if you need..Thank You

Comment: Are you really sure the value of $count is 50? could you try to output this value in console.log to make sure?

Comment: What is the count of "arr" elements? 43?

Comment: Why is `total` a string? Presumably you echo an integer and then you quote it

Comment: if total is "50" your code will run 49 times - perhaps the server "fails" when id > 43 - as you have no error handling at all, it's going to be hard for you to find out why your (probably server side) code has a problem with id > 43

Comment: `JSON.stringify(eval('(' + data + ')'));arr = $.parseJSON(json);` well that looks interesting to be sure!! what the heck is your server returning that you need to do that code smell for!

Comment: Hi guys, here is some information for you :- 1. whether the $count value is 50 or 80 or 100 it will execute only 43 times.  2. count of arr elements are (three) 3